# elasticsearch date-range query 0 hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query my docs with a date-range query.

Doing a get for one of my docs gives me something like that:

```
{
  "_index": "offer",
  "_type": "offer",
  "_id": "offer3",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "offer": {
      "properties": {
        "starts_at": "12/10/2015T14:27:49.197962+00:00",
        "ends_at": "14/11/2016T07:59:49.197962+00:00",
        "duration": "1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a query in this form, where I have the exact value of ends_at copied into my query, but I still get 0 hits. Where am I going wrong?

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/offer/offer/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "ends_at": {
        "lte": "14/11/2016T07:59:49.197962+00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the format of your `ends_at` date field ? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/session/_mapping/session`?

Comment: The format is dateOptionalTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date format is `dateOptionalTime` your documents need to have the correct [ISO8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), i.e. either `yyyy-MM-dd` (without time) or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` (with time)

In your case that would mean that your dates need to be formatted like this instead:

```
2016-11-14T07:59:49.197+00:00
```

You need to wipe your index, fix your mapping and re-index your data properly.

Then you'll be able to search using this query:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/offer/offer/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
  "properties.ends_at": {
     "lte":"2016-11-14T07:59:49.197+00:00"
  }
}
}
}'
```

Comment: ok, so now I have fixed the formatting. I ran the same query you posted and I still get 0 hits

Comment: And you wiped your index, re-installed the proper mapping, and re-indexed all your data with the proper formatting?

Comment: Actually, it seems you're not querying the same index. Your document shows it is stored in the `offer` index, but your query is on the `session` index. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Also your `offer` document seems to have a `properties` object field which might be there by mistake. If that's intended, then you need to query `properties.ends_at` instead of `ends_at`

Comment: ahh sorry, thats a mistake, I'll edit that now. But Im querying the same index